# Google font 'Varela Round' doesn't support font-weight in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

I'm building a website using the Google Webfont 'Varela Round', which obviously only ships with a font-weight of 400. In parts of my website where I wanna have a bold font like in headings or links, I can without any problems assign `font-weight: 600;` or `font-weight: bold;` via CSS and it works perfectly.

Only Google Chrome of all browsers doesn't seem to support this and would still render the font with normal weight. Is there any way to achieve a bolder weight in Chrome with this font?

Comment: Chrome applies synthetic (algorithmic) bolding, so you probably have some error in your code. You should post code that actually reproduces the problem (and identify the browser version and platform). OTOH, synthetic bolding, aka. faux bold, should simply not be used even though browsers generally produce it (in different ways). It’s possible that you just don’t recognize Chrome’s faux bold as bolder than regular.

Answer (score 0):

This font is only available in `font-weight: 400;` and thus Google Chrome only supports this. This browser does not support another `font-weight` if it is not included.
That's one of the problems of Googel Chrome.